# Can interpolation be limited to positive values?

Tags: d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I currently use LineChart in order to display discrete data across 7 points on the x-axis (the days of the week). To improve the appearance of the chart, I use `interpolate('monotone')` to make the line smoother:

[image]

As you can see, however, this causes the line to at some points slip beneath the x-axis. Is there any way I can prevent this? The graph itself is created like this:

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .interpolate('monotone')
        .width(400)
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .showLegend(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, anonymous person. It helps not letting me know what you find wrong with the question.

Comment: You can't prevent this explicitly; I would choose a different interpolation here.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff could you post that as an answer so that I can accept it please? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent this explicitly; I would choose a different interpolation here.